# Compare sharpness at subpixel level

Tags: image-processing, blur

I'm working on algorithms for a camera system (which go down to sub-pixel precision). Until now, I just worked on a recorded dataset, but I'm now moving to real cameras.

My question is how to find the "perfect" sharpness? Down to about pixel level, it's rather easy : I printed some patterns ([an USAF resolution chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1951_USAF_resolution_test_chart), consisting in patterns of 3 black bars of various sizes), and I was looking at the smallest patterns where I can still see the 3 black bars. The best I can obtain this way is 3 blackish bars one pixel think, with 2 light-grayish bars in between.

If the bars are distant by less than 1 pixel, I will of course no longer see them separately (so I will just see gray).

How can I compare or measure the sharpness at sub-pixel distances (ie ideally, each pixel should be the average of the light coming from the surface corresponding to that pixel in the image, without mixing with the neighbor pixel).

So how can I tell which image is sharper (or how sharp each image is) once sharpness is at subpixel level?

The images are "the same" (ie I just change the parameters of the camera, not the scene), and I can print whatever pattern will work best).

Comment: If the sharpness is “at subpixel level” then you will get **aliasing**. Ideally the sensor has a pixel density sufficient to properly sample the image projected by the optics — it should be the optics that determine the resolution (sharpness), not the detector. If the sampling density is too low (often the case with consumer-grade cameras), they usually put an anti-aliasing filter over the detector. In this situation, making sub-pixel analysis of the image is much harder and limited.

Comment: We do ourself the hardware setup (buying the sensors and the lenses separatly). The lenses are recommended for up to 5Mpixels (the resolution of our sensor). So you mean it would be better to use worse optics?!? For the sup-pixel processing, it's mainly feature matching (ie template matching) : I look for the best matching at pixel level, then compute the optimal sub-pixel localization round the pixel-level localization, in order to improve accuracy